# Getting JavaScript heap out of memory Error on compiling Angular 6 Project

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, compiler-errors

I'm facing the following error on compiling Angular 6 project

```
[14428:00903BB0]   295280 ms: Mark-sweep 1009.7 (1044.8) -> 999.5 (1042.2) MB, 1396.7 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.172, current mu = 0.167) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[14428:00903BB0]   297414 ms: Mark-sweep 1002.4 (1042.2) -> 1000.0 (1043.0) MB, 1896.1 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.138, current mu = 0.111) allocation failure GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 015779E7]
Security context: 0x29d40451 <JSObject>
    1: /* anonymous */ [49FD5AAD] [D:\AFX Project\AFX-FE\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-node.js:~342] [pc=2342B993](this=0x048d0d79 <JSGlobal Object>,0x0f969469 <String[4]:  || >,0x0a09e985 <Object map = 1D91D341>)
    2: SourceNode_walk [2BF45719] [D:\AFX Project\AFX-FE\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-node.js:~221] [pc=0D94C7F5](this=0x362c81d5 <SourceNode map...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Writing Node.js report to file: report.20220322.165336.14428.0.001.json
Node.js report completed
```

The solutions I tried:

```
1. set environment variable to NODE_OPTIONS : --max_old_space_size=4096
2. run the command node --max-old-space-size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve -o
```

Both the solutions didn't work. my project specifications are the following:
**Angular v6.2.9 , Node v12.14.0 and Npm v6.13.4**

Comment: Can you try using node 8.9.x or later minor?

Comment: are you suggesting to down grade the node v12.14.0 to 8.9.x?

Comment: Yes, pls downgrade and try

Comment: @rohithpoya downgrading didn't helped

Comment: Maybe `NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192` ?